# oracle - path passing by multiple nodes structure

Tags: oracle

I have the following oracle 12c tables structure:

table1:

```
path_id    node_1         node1_port          node_2        node2_port
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1      France         France_port1          Italy        Italy_port1
    1      Italy          Italy_port1          France        France_port1
    1      Italy          Italy_port2          Belgium       Belgium_port1
    1      Belgium         Belgium_port1        Italy        Italy_port2
    1      Belgium         Belgium_port2        Sweden       Sweden_port1
    1      Sweden         Sweden_port1          Belgium       Belgium_port2
    2      Belgium         Belgium_port1        Germany       Germany_port1
    2      Germany         Germany_port1        Belgium       Belgium_port1
```

table2:

```
path_id  start_node   start_node_port  end_node    end_node_port
----------------------------------------------------------------
   1       France     France_port1      Sweden       Sweden_port1
   2       Belgium    Belgium_port1     Germany      Germany_port1
```

where path id has multiple nodes and node_1_port and node_2_port represent the hops of this path.
so for example path_id = 1 start from France and end in Sweden (as per table2), passing by Italy and Belgium(as per table1), while path_id = 2 start from Belgium and end in Germany.

can you give me some hints how to proceed as I'm still new to oracle.

**EDIT:**

I edited the post to make it a little more realistic.

In addition, node_1 and node_2 can be random names. the order of the hops will be got from the connection of node_1 and node_2 : France is connected to Italy , then Italy connected to Belgium , then Belgium connected to Sweden , then the order of the path is : France-->Italy-->Belgium-->Sweden , knowing that the port connecting Italy to France is different than the port connecting Italy to Belgium , and both ports must be included in the final table. It's a bit complicated , I'm not able to get it right.

this is the needed output:

```
    path_id   node_name        node_port     order
---------------------------------------------------
       1        France       France_port1      1  
       1        Italy        Italy_port1       2
       1        Italy        Italy_port2       3  
       1        Belgium      Belgium_port1     4  
       1        Belgium      Belgium_port2     5
       1        Sweden       Sweden_port1      6  
       2        Belgium      Belgium_port1     1  
       2        Germany      Germany_port1     2
```

**This is what I reached so far , knowing that I was forced to use loops as I couldn't think of any other way.
Is there a way to get the result using a query without loops as I have around 1M records in table1.**

```
create table table_final (path_id integer,node_name varchar2(50),node_port varchar2(50),order_rec integer);
declare 
id integer :=1;
start_node varchar2(50);
end_node varchar2(50);
start_node_port varchar2(50);
end_node_port varchar2(50);
cnt integer:=1;
cnt_or integer:=1;
cnt1 integer:=0;

 TYPE nodes_arr IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
nodes   nodes_arr;
 TYPE nodes_ports_arr IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
ports   nodes_ports_arr;
id_cnt integer;
BEGIN
select max(path_id) into id_cnt from table2;
while id <= id_cnt
LOOP
select start_node,end_node,start_node_port,end_node_port into nodes(1),end_node,ports(1),end_node_port 
from table2 where path_id = id;
start_node:=nodes(1);
start_node_port:=ports(1);
insert into table_final
select id,nodes(1),ports(1),cnt from dual; 
commit;
while start_node!=end_node
LOOP
cnt:=cnt+1;
cnt_or:=cnt_or+1;
if cnt =2 
THEN
select node_2,node2_port into nodes(cnt),ports(cnt) 
from table1 where path_id=id and node_1=nodes(cnt-1) and node_2!=node_1;
ELSE
select node_2,node2_port into nodes(cnt),ports(cnt) 
from table1 where path_id=id and node_1=nodes(cnt-1)  and node_2!=node_1 and node_2!=nodes(cnt-2) ;
END IF;
insert into table_final
select id,nodes(cnt),ports(cnt),cnt_or from dual;

select NVL(count(*),0) into cnt1 from table1 where path_id=id and node_1=nodes(cnt)  and node1_port !=ports(cnt);
if cnt1=1
THEN
cnt_or:=cnt_or+1;
insert into table_final
select id,node_1,node1_port,cnt_or
from table1 where path_id=id and node_1=nodes(cnt)  and node1_port !=ports(cnt);
END IF;
start_node:=nodes(cnt);
start_node_port:=ports(cnt);


commit;
END LOOP;
cnt:=1;
cnt_or:=1;
id:=id+1;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: From your edit its hard to guess the correct output. Please edit the question once again and post your expected output as per your new requirement.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai the expected output is now posted in the Edit section

Comment: I guess, until or unless you didn't give us more concrete data to develop a logic for you, we wold not be able to provide any help. From your sample data below answer seems absolutely correct. Please edit your sample data. We will try our level best to provide you more accurate result.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I replaced the nodes with countries names. I think it's more concrete now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see any usage of table2 here. You can simply remove duplicates from table1 itself as following:

```
Select t.*, 
row_number() 
 over (partition by path_id order by to_number(replace(node_name, 'node', ''))) as order_
From
(Select distinct path_id,
Node_name,
Node_name_1_para
From table1) t
Order by path_id, order_;
```

**-- Update --**

As per the comments, you should try this query:

```
Select t1.path_id,
T1.node_name
T.node_name_1_para,
Row_number() over (partition by t1.path_id order by null) as order_
From
Table1 t1 join table2 t2
On (t1.path_id = t2.path_id
And t1.node_1 between t2.start_node and t2.end_node);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: table2 is used to specify the start and end nodes. Also I cannot depend on the node id to order the hops as it's not sequential (the example in my question is just to simplify things , while in reality the nodes are not named node1 , node2 ...)

Comment: Then how will start and end nodes behaves? Can we apply condition like table1.node_name between tabl2.start_node and table2.end_node?

Comment: No, node_1 and node_2 can be random names , we cannot depend on between start and end nodes. the order of the hops will be got from the connection of node_1 and node_2 : nodeA is connected to nodeB , then nodeB connected to nodeC , then nodeC connected to nodeD , then the order of the path is : nodeA-->nodeB-->nodeC-->nodeD , knowing that the port connecting nodeB to nodeA is different than the port connecting nodeB to nodeC , and both ports must be included in the final table. It's a bit complicated , I'm not able to get it right,

Comment: Please recheck my question as I adjusted to input to make it more realistic